# ReCreating threads in python

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I'm using the following template to recreate threads that I need to run into infinity.
I want to know if this template is scalable in terms of memory. Are threaded destroyed properly?

```
import threading
import time

class aLazyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(10)
        print "I don not want to work :("

class aWorkerThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print "I want to work!!!!!!!"

threadA = aLazyThread()
threadA.start()
threadB = aWorkerThread()
threadB.start()

while True:

    if not (threadA.isAlive()):
        threadA = aLazyThread()
        threadA.start()

    if not (threadB.isAlive()):
        threadB = aWorkerThread()
        threadB.start()
```

The thing that bother me is the following picture taking in eclipse which show debug info, and It seems that thread are stacking it.

[image: Thread counts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I see nothing wrong with the image. There's the main thread and the 2 threads that you created (according to the code, 3 threads are supposed to be running at any time)
2. Like any other *Python* objects, threads are garbage collected when they're not used; e.g. in your main while cycle, when you instantiate the class (let's say `aLazyThread`), the old `threadA` value is destroyed (maybe not exactly at that point, but shortly after)
3. The main while cycle, could also use a *sleep* (e.g. `time.sleep(1)`), otherwise it will consume the processor, uselessly checking if the other threads are running.